# How to move the estimate shipping block to a CMS page in Magento?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I'm trying to move the 'Estimate Shipping' block, that usually sits in the Cart, to a CMS page.

I've successfully moved the form, however, upon clicking the 'Estimate..' button, I get redirected to the Cart.

I've tried changing

```php
action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>"
```

to the cms page url:

```
    `action="getUrl('delivery/estimatePost') ?>"`
```

and also a general:

```php
action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/estimatePost') ?>"`
```

but then I just get a 404.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep `action="getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>"` or otherwise you will need to create a different controller action which generate a different block content to allow to display in your cms block but it's not so easy as you try to do.

The string `checkout/cart/estimatePost` means module/controller/action, if you change that of course he won't find your page. That's why you need to develop a solution more complex with a mix of controller and based on the block classes used while the action `estimatePost` is called.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not sure I even know where to start with that! Any tips or tutorials you know of?